# How to process logically related rows after ItemReader in SpringBatch?

Tags: spring-batch

## Scenario

To make it simple, let's suppose I have an ItemReader that returns me 25 rows.

1. The first 10 rows belong to student A
2. The next 5 belong to student B
3. and the 10 remaining belong to student C

I want to aggregate them together logically say by **studentId** and flatten them **to end up with one row per student.**

## Problem

If I understand correctly, setting the commit interval to 5 will do the following:

1. Send 5 rows to the Processor (which will aggregate them or do any business logic I tell it to).
2. After Processed will write 5 rows.
3. Then it will do it again for the next 5 rows and so on.

If that is true, then for the next five I will have to check the already written ones, get them out aggregate them to the ones that I am currently processing and write them again.

I personally do no like that.

1. What is the best practice to handle a situation like this in Spring Batch?

## Alternative

Sometimes I feel that it is much easier to write a regular Spring JDBC main program and then I have full control of what I want to do. However, I wanted to take advantage of of the job repository state monitoring of the job, ability to restart, skip, job and step listeners....

## My Spring Batch Code

My **module-context.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Example job to get you started. It provides a skeleton for a typical batch application.</description>

    <batch:job id="job1">
        <batch:step id="step1"  >           
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" start-limit="100" >             
                 <batch:chunk reader="attendanceItemReader"
                              processor="attendanceProcessor" 
                              writer="attendanceItemWriter" 
                              commit-interval="10" 
                 />

            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job> 

    <bean id="attendanceItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"> 
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="sourceDataSource"/>
        </property> 
        <property name="sql"                                                    
                  value="select s.student_name ,s.student_id ,fas.attendance_days ,fas.attendance_value from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students s on fas.student_key = s.student_key inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds on fas.school_key = ds.school_key inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd on fas.school_dates_key = dsd.school_dates_key where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0 and ds.school_code = ? and s.student_activity_indicator = 'Active' and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = 'G1' and s.student_current_grade_level = 'Gr 9' order by s.student_id"/>
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="attendanceStatementSetter"/>           
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="attendanceRowMapper"/> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="attendanceStatementSetter" class="edu.kdc.visioncards.preparedstatements.AttendanceStatementSetter"/>

    <bean id="attendanceRowMapper" class="edu.kdc.visioncards.rowmapper.AttendanceRowMapper"/>

    <bean id="attendanceProcessor" class="edu.kdc.visioncards.AttendanceProcessor" />  

    <bean id="attendanceItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"> 
        <property name="resource" value="file:target/outputs/passthrough.txt"/> 
        <property name="lineAggregator"> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" /> 
        </property> 
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

My supporting classes for the Reader.

A PreparedStatementSetter

```
package edu.kdc.visioncards.preparedstatements;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;

public class AttendanceStatementSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {

    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

        ps.setInt(1, 7);

    }

}
```

and a RowMapper

```
package edu.kdc.visioncards.rowmapper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import edu.kdc.visioncards.dto.AttendanceDTO;

public class AttendanceRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<AttendanceDTO> {

    public static final String STUDENT_NAME = "STUDENT_NAME";
    public static final String STUDENT_ID = "STUDENT_ID";
    public static final String ATTENDANCE_DAYS = "ATTENDANCE_DAYS";
    public static final String ATTENDANCE_VALUE = "ATTENDANCE_VALUE";

    public AttendanceDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        AttendanceDTO dto = new AttendanceDTO();
        dto.setStudentId(rs.getString(STUDENT_ID));
        dto.setStudentName(rs.getString(STUDENT_NAME));
        dto.setAttDays(rs.getInt(ATTENDANCE_DAYS));
        dto.setAttValue(rs.getInt(ATTENDANCE_VALUE));

        return dto;
    }
}
```

My processor

```
package edu.kdc.visioncards;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

import edu.kdc.visioncards.dto.AttendanceDTO;

public class AttendanceProcessor implements ItemProcessor<AttendanceDTO, Map<Integer, AttendanceDTO>> {

    private Map<Integer, AttendanceDTO> map = new HashMap<Integer, AttendanceDTO>();

    public Map<Integer, AttendanceDTO> process(AttendanceDTO dto) throws Exception {

        if(map.containsKey(new Integer(dto.getStudentId()))){

            AttendanceDTO attDto = (AttendanceDTO)map.get(new Integer(dto.getStudentId()));
            attDto.setAttDays(attDto.getAttDays() + dto.getAttDays());
            attDto.setAttValue(attDto.getAttValue() + dto.getAttValue());

        }else{
            map.put(new Integer(dto.getStudentId()), dto);
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

## My concerns from code above

In the Processor, I create a HashMap and as I process the rows I check whether I already have that Student in the Map, if it's not there I add it. If it's already there I grab the it get the values that I am interested in and add them with the row that I am currently processing.

After that, Spring Batch Framework writes to a File according to my configuration

My question is as follows:

1. I do not want it to go to the writer. I want to process all the remaining rows. How do I keep this Map that I have created in memory for the next set of rows that need to go through this same Processor? Everytime, a row is processed through AttendanceProcessor the Map is initialized. Should I put the Map initialization in a static block?

Answer (score 7):

In my application I created a `CollectingJdbcCursorItemReader` that extends the standard [`JdbcCursorItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) and performs exactly what you need.  Internally it uses my `CollectingRowMapper`: an extension of the standard [`RowMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) that maps multiple related rows to one object.

Here is the code of the ItemReader, the code of `CollectingRowMapper` interface, and an abstract implementation of it, is available in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346006/685806) of mine.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

/**
 * A JdbcCursorItemReader that uses a {@link CollectingRowMapper}.
 * Like the superclass this reader is not thread-safe.
 * 
 * @author Pino Navato
 **/
public class CollectingJdbcCursorItemReader<T> extends JdbcCursorItemReader<T> {

    private CollectingRowMapper<T> rowMapper;
    private boolean firstRead = true;


    /**
     * Accepts a {@link CollectingRowMapper} only.
     **/
    @Override
    public void setRowMapper(RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
        this.rowMapper = (CollectingRowMapper<T>)rowMapper;
        super.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
     }


    /**
     * Read next row and map it to item.
     **/
    @Override
    protected T doRead() throws Exception {
        if (rs == null) {
            throw new ReaderNotOpenException("Reader must be open before it can be read.");
        }

        try {
            if (firstRead) {
                if (!rs.next()) {  //Subsequent calls to next() will be executed by rowMapper
                    return null;
                }
                firstRead = false;
            } else if (!rowMapper.hasNext()) {
                return null;
            }
            T item = readCursor(rs, getCurrentItemCount());
            return item;
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("Attempt to process next row failed", getSql(), se);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected T readCursor(ResultSet rs, int currentRow) throws SQLException {
        T result = super.readCursor(rs, currentRow);
        setCurrentItemCount(rs.getRow());
        return result;
    }

}
```

You can use it just like the classic `JdbcCursorItemReader`: the only requirement is that you provide it a `CollectingRowMapper` instead of the classic `RowMapper`.

Comment: Clever solution. I ended up using this for my spring batch app.

Comment: @Pino I've some doubts regarding the above solution. How can I get in touch with you?

Comment: @hbamithkumara, only through this comments section.

Comment: Fine.. How can I process the entire chunk at once? Basically I need something like this  MyItemProcessor<List<ObjectDao>, List<ObjectDao>> and MyItemWriter<List<ObjectDao> Is this possible?

Comment: @hbamithkumara, do you mean how to process all input data at once? Spring-batch works in chunks because, generally speaking, loading all input data could take too much memory.  Furthermore, in Spring-batch design, ItemProcessor and ItemWriter work on *single beans* loaded by ItemReader, not on *DAOs*.  In my solution each bean contains a list of logically-related items but they are single beans as required by Spring-batch. I think that reading a good tutorial of Spring-batch could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I always follow this pattern:

1. I make my reader scope to be "step", and in @PostConstruct I fetch
   the results, and put them in a Map
2. In processor, I convert the associatedCollection into writable list,
   and send the writable list
3. In ItemWriter, I persist the writable item(s) depending on the case

Answer (score 1):

because you changed your question i add a new answer

if the students are ordered then there is no need for list/map, you could use exactly one studentObject on the processor to keep the "current" and aggregate on it until there is a new one (read: id change)

if the students are not ordered you will never know when a specific student is "finished" and you'd have to keep all students in a map which can't be written until the end of the complete read sequence

beware:

- **the processor needs to know when the reader is exhausted**
- **its hard to get it working with any commit-rate and "id" concept** if you aggregate items that are somehow identical the processor just can't know if the currently processed item is the last one
- basically the usecase is either solved at reader level completely or at writer level (see other answer)

```java
private SimpleItem currentItem;
private StepExecution stepExecution;

@Override
public SimpleItem process(SimpleItem newItem) throws Exception {
    SimpleItem returnItem = null;

    if (currentItem == null) {
        currentItem = new SimpleItem(newItem.getId(), newItem.getValue());
    } else if (currentItem.getId() == newItem.getId()) {
        // aggregate somehow
        String value = currentItem.getValue() + newItem.getValue();
        currentItem.setValue(value);
    } else {
        // "clone"/copy currentItem
        returnItem = new SimpleItem(currentItem.getId(), currentItem.getValue());
        // replace currentItem
        currentItem = newItem;
    }

    // reader exhausted?
    if(stepExecution.getExecutionContext().containsKey("readerExhausted")
            && (Boolean)stepExecution.getExecutionContext().get("readerExhausted")
            && currentItem.getId() == stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("lastItemId")) {
        returnItem = new SimpleItem(currentItem.getId(), currentItem.getValue());
    }

    return returnItem;
}
```

Comment: where do you get "readerExhausted" from? Is that a key from SpringBatch? I do not find it anywhere in the docs. Also does StepExecution need a **set** or SpringBatch just picks it up the way you have it above?

Comment: no you'd have to implement a reader by yourself wich does that, for working with a StepExecutionListener see http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#interceptingStepExecution

Answer (score 0):

basically you talk about batch processing with changing IDs(1), where the batch has to keep track of the change

for spring/spring-batch we talk about:

- ItemWriter which checks the list of items for an id change
- before the change the items are stored in a temporary datastore(2) (List, Map, whatever), and are not *written* out
- when the id changes, the aggregating/flattening business code runs on the items in the datastore and one item should be written, now the datastore can be used for the next items with the next id
- this concept needs a reader which tells the step "i'm exhausted" to properly flush the temporary datastore on end of items (file/database)

here a rough and simple code example

```java
@Override
public void write(List<? extends SimpleItem> items) throws Exception {

    // setup with first sharedId at startup
    if (currentId == null){
        currentId = items.get(0).getSharedId();
    }

    // check for change of sharedId in input
    // keep items in temporary dataStore until id change of input
    // call delegate if there is an id change or if the reader is exhausted
    for (SimpleItem item : items) {
        // already known sharedId, add to tempData
        if (item.getSharedId() == currentId) {
            tempData.add(item);
        } else {
            // or new sharedId, write tempData, empty it, keep new id
            // the delegate does the flattening/aggregating
            delegate.write(tempData);
            tempData.clear();
            currentId = item.getSharedId();
            tempData.add(item);
        }
    }

    // check if reader is exhausted, flush tempData
    if ((Boolean) stepExecution.getExecutionContext().get("readerExhausted")
            && tempData.size() > 0) {
        delegate.write(tempData);
        // optional delegate.clear(); 
    }
}
```

(1)assuming the items are ordered by an ID (can be composite too)

(2)a hashmap spring bean for thread safety

Comment: so in the processor is where I do you 2nd and 3rd bullet points. What I am not understanding is that when that logic has completed, it will go to a Writer right? In that Writer I do not want to write to any db or file because the next group of rows might still belong to an item in the list that its in memory. How can I keep that list of objects (temporary datastore) that I have created during processing step still accessible when going through the processing step again for the next 5 rows?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have added my source code and a question after the source code see if it adds clarification to my concern

Answer (score 0):

Use Step Execution Listener and store the records as map to the StepExecutionContext , you can then group them in the writer or writer listener and write it at a time