# Merge periodes in java

Tags: spring-batch

I am working with Spring batch. the batch will read several records each time from the database which look like this

> personId |fromDate|      toDate  |     someCode
>
> *100   |    05-05-2011 | 31-12-2011   |     A
>
> *100    |   01-01-2012 | 31-12-2012  |      A
>
> 100     |  01-01-2013 | 03-03-2013 |       B
>
> 101     |  05-05-2011 | 31-12-2011 |       A
>
> *periodes to be merged.

What i want to do is to merge the periodes which has the same code and same personId, but not diffrent code or personId.

The first question is can i chunk this step? the problem is that commite intervals are static and i might not get all the priodes for a person in one chunk. is it possible to have dynamic chunks based on how many records for a person are on the table?

the next question is what is the best way to merge the periods? periods should be merged if the toDate is 31-12 and the next period starts from 01-01 of next year.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837487/how-to-process-logically-related-rows-after-itemreader-in-springbatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solv the problem with using 2 pointer in each object. one which point to the previous period and one to the next period.
For chunking i needed to read all rows with same person id and aggregate them.