# SQL RowMapper with List of objects

Tags: java, sql

I am having trouble mapping data from a database to my objects. Here is how my object are setup.

```
public class Report{
    private int reportID;
    private String reportName;
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    // getters and setters
}
public class Article{
    private int articleID;
    private String articleName;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The data from the database comes in the following format:

```
ReportID  | Report Name  | ArticleID  | ArticleName
-----------------------------------------------------
1           Name1          1            Name1 
1           Name1          2            Name2
1           Name1          3            Name3 
2           Name2          1            Name1 
2           Name2          2            Name2 
3           Name3          1            Name1
```

As can be seen, each report can have 1-n articles. This is reflected in the pojo structure.
My issue is mapping the result set to the objects.

My DAO has the following method:

```
public List<Report> getReports(){

    String SQL = "Select * FROM report_table";
    List<Report> reports = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new RowMapper<Report>(){

        @Override
        public Report mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{

            // here I need to return each record
            // but I need to add the articles to the record's list first!
            return null;
        }
    });

    return reports;
}
```

How can I go about mapping the articles to the reports?

Comment: Take the data out of the `ResultSet` and put it into `Report` objects. Did you miss the entire basics of Java?

Comment: check. this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455220/spring-jdbc-rowmapper-usage-for-eager-fetches.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Deendayal. That was exactly what I needed!!

Comment: Found answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455220/spring-jdbc-rowmapper-usage-for-eager-fetches.