# Spring Batch - How to have my JdbcCursorItemReader returning List (whole chunk) to ItemProcessor as i want to process records at same time

Tags: spring-batch, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have developed a spring batch job which reads from database using JdbcCursorItemReader, process it and writes to kafka topic.
The database table returns rows which has same Id as some columns have repeating values. So i have to group such rows and build a message in ItemProcessor class for single Id and repeating values column as arrayList in the message.

[image]

So i want to send the whole list of records read in ItemReader and process them to create a map based on Id and build message which will be written to kafka topic.

Comment: I'm not sure the chunk-oriented processing model is suitable to group items as you describe.

Comment: Can we do something in ItemReader class to group the records based on the key and pass the one record to the ItemProcessor class?

Comment: I was able to do this. Please refer to this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837487/how-to-process-logically-related-rows-after-itemreader-in-springbatch/46346438#46346438