# How to group the records in Spring Batch 5.x so that every thread/execution is dedicated for one group of records

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch 5 & I have a use-case where I need to group the input records (from database) based on `bookingId`. Now the processor should pick the records group by group from the reader output. Also, the writer should write output group by group.

How can we achieve this with `RepositoryItemReader`. I'm struggling to find a sample code for Spring Batch 5.

Comment: About grouping logically related records see my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346438/685806 but it does not use `RepositoryItemReader`.

Comment: @Pino I need to group the records based on a database column, and NOT database rows.

Comment: Not sure if I got your point but a simple `order by bookingId` clause added to the SQL statement of JdbcItemReader should do the trick.

Comment: @Mar-Z 
can you explain how this would work? when we order it by `bookingId`, how to ensure that the processor gets the list of records that has only a particular `bookingId` (list containing all same) ?  I need to ensure that the next execution of processor should take a list with different `bookingId`

Comment: The processor doesn't work on a list of items. It takes a single item (= database row) from the reader. Only the writer works on a list of items gathered in a chunk. My proposal of ordering was to process items in a desired sequence.

Comment: @Mar-Z I want one bookingId records to be executed in one thread/execution clubbed as a group. I do not want the same bookingId to be executed across multiple threads.

Comment: Rahul, my solution groups records having the same valute on one or more db column, just like you want. Read it better.

Answer (score 0):

The chunk-oriented processing model is **not** suitable for this use case. No matter how you group items in your query (sql `group by` for instance) , items from the same group could span multiple chunks when returned from the reader. Therefore, it is impossible to have a chunk per group.

Of course it is technically possible to abuse the pattern and find a way to implement that requirement, but every solution would not be clean as it would use a model for use case that is was not designed for.

The "cleanest" way I see to address this is to use a partitioned step, where partitions are created by the grouping criteria (`bookingId` in your case).

Comment: I don't agree, see my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346438/685806

Comment: @Pino That solution falls in the "abusing the model for a use case that is was not designed for" category, and has a few issues: 1) it requires the input to be sorted (as documented, but this is a hard constraint), 2) it returns a list of items and not individual items and 3) one could end up with a chunk of lists of items from different groups (for example, with a chunkSize=2 I can have one list of 10 items with groupId=x and another list of 50 items of gropupId=y) which is not what the OP asked for in : "the writer should write output group by group.".

Comment: Again, and as mentioned in the answer, while it is technically possible to implement grouping/aggregation with that model, the model itself is not suitable for such use cases.

Comment: About "abusing the model", I think it could be said of any class that extends a given class to add a new feature. About chunkSize, with my solution it refers to the collecting objects, not to the underlying records.

Answer (score 0):

@Pino's solution has to be modified a little bit with usage of SingleItemPeekableItemReader to peek to the next record outside the original chunk  to handle the concerns raised by @Mahmoud Ben Hassine regarding chunking but it is not the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: It looks more of a comment than an answer to the question